# Структуризация (иерархия) связанных данных

Tags: php

Есть база данных:

```
name   sysname   mother
Алиса  Alisa     sys
Вася   Vasia     Alisa
Дима   Dima      Kate
Петя   Petia     sys
Коля   Kolia     Alisa
Алена  Alena     sys
Катя   Kate      Alena
```

Необходимо отфильтровать массив таким образом, чтобы в результате получилась очередность, в которой за родительским элементом следуют все дочерние. Если в дочернем элементе есть дети, то они должны быть обнаружены и выведены соответствующим образом.

То есть должна получиться следующая картина:

```
Алиса
  Вася
  Коля
Петя
Алена
  Катя
     Дима


 foreach ($row as $value){
   $catalog = "catalog";
   if ($value['mothercat']==$catalog)
   {
   echo $value['name'].'</br>';
   $finder = 1;
   }
   else
   if ($finder == 1)
       {
       $catalog = $value['mothercat'];
            foreach ($row as $val){
            if ($val['mothercat']==$catalog)
            echo '<STRONG>'. $val['mothercat'].'</STRONG></br>';
           }
        unset ($finder);
        }
 }
```

Comment: А Вы пробовали рекурсивно это сделать? Покажите код что вы сделали, легче будет ответить. Вариантов много

Comment: @Saidolim Djuraev Добавил в пример, ту ересь, что у меня получилась. Не могу придумать адекватное решение через рекурсию.